# get thumbnail from UIImagePickerController when using CAMERA (not album)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

It's very easy to get a thumbnail when using the ALBUM with UIImagePickerController.

It's even easy to get a thumbnail from a VIDEO.

But when you're using the CAMERA,

```
self.cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

and you come back to

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

How do you quickly get a thumbnail?

Note, I'm not particularly trying to SAVE the image .. I want to use the image from the camera (imagine then using it in a drawing screen, or for image processing, etc.)

Below, a naive category that turns the image in to a 128.128 image. But it's way too slow.

Many apps move **very quickly from the camera, to the next screen** (say, editing the image or drawing on it).  What's the technique?  Cheers

```
-(UIImage *)squareAndSmall
{
// this category works fine to make a 128.128 thumbnail,
// but it is very slow
CGSize finalsize = CGSizeMake(128,128);

CGFloat scale = MAX(
  finalsize.width/self.size.width,
  finalsize.height/self.size.height);
CGFloat width = self.size.width * scale;
CGFloat height = self.size.height * scale;

//uses the central area, say....
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(
  (finalsize.width - width)/2.0f,
  (finalsize.height - height)/2.0f,
  width, height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(finalsize, NO, 0);
[self drawInRect:imageRect];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using "AssetLibrary.framework" to write the image to your camera roll and it will automatically create a thumbnail representation for you. Moreover, as this process is asynchronous, it will certainly be a performance boost for the app.

Try some thing like the following:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

////.........your code

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    /////.........
    UIImage* img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];  
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[img CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[img imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
        if (error) {  
            NSLog(@"error");  
            return;
        } 

        [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
            [self.imageViewer setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset aspectRatioThumbnail]]]; //self.imageViewer is a UIImageView to display thumbnail
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load captured image.");
        }];
    }];  
    [library release];

    //................
}

////......rest of your code
```

I have not tested the code but I hope, it should fulfill your purpose. Please make sure to add a reference of "AssetLibrary.framework" to your project before you try and let me know if it worked out for you.

Comment: BTW Ayan, I am not saving the image at all, and don't want to save the image - I just want to get a thumbnail on the fly.  But thanks for the informative answer here!  Cheers

Comment: @Joe unfortunately asset lib only generates thumbnail and any other associated image(`fullResolutionImage`/`fullScreenImage`) only during the writing process :(